# git merge master not merging changes/conflicts from master into local branch

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to merge changes from master(locally) to my feature branch, but I'm not able to. Here's what I've tried

I checked out my remote github branch and now have a local branch that's tracking the changes:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/ABC-1849-add-new-changes
  remotes/origin/master
  ... 
  other remotes
  ...

$ git checkout ABC-1849-add-new-changes
Branch ABC-1849-add-new-changes set up to track remote branch ABC-1849-add-new-changes from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'ABC-1849-add-new-changes'
```

At this point, if I do a

```
$ git diff master
```

I see at least 7 files that have conflicts. I need to merge these changes from master on to my branch. So I do:

```
$ git merge master
```

And all I see is:

```
Auto-merging random_modules.mk
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
random_modules.mk | 1 +
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

None of the files with conflicts are showing up. I don't see any message saying there's merge conflict. If I do a diff with master, all the conflicts still show up

Comment: If you see these 7 files in git diff, I guess you mean "7 files with differences" rather than "7 conflicts", correct ?

Comment: Yes, my bad. 7 files with differences

Comment: ok, no prob ; can you edit your question to reflect that please ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `git diff master` by itself *cannot* tell you whether there will be merge conflicts.  It takes *two separate* `git diff` commands, whose output must be scanned carefully, to find out if there will be conflicts.

(Why do you believe, based on a single `git diff master`, that there are 7 files that have conflicts?  If we figure that out, we can probably explain where you have gone wrong here.)

Comment: The changes that I've added in these seven files touch the same functions as the ones in master. I'm assuming that would cause a merge conflict, cause in this instance git wouldn't automatically know how to select the changes?

Comment: I did a `git merge master --no-ff --no-commit` and I see:
Auto-merging common/abc/file_1\n
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in common/abc/file_1
Auto-merging common/abc/file_2
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in common/abc/file_2
Auto-merging common/def/file_3
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in common/def/file_3
Auto-merging common/file_4
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in common/file_4
Recorded preimage for 'common/file_4'
Recorded preimage for 'common/def/file_3'
Recorded preimage for 'common/abc/file_2'
Recorded preimage for 'in common/abc/file_1'

Comment: OK: that shows the 7 conflicts you mention. But you also show that `git merge master` produced *no* conflicts. Are you saying that if you run `git merge master --no-ff --no-commit`, you get 7 conflicts, and then if you subsequently run `git merge --abort` and then `git merge master` you get no conflicts? That would be very weird.

Answer (score 0):

If the differences come from commits on your branch, it is only normal that git keeps these changes, and updates only the changes coming from master.

The diff you may want to look at is :

```
# if you haven't merged master into my/branch yet :
git diff my/branch...master   # three dots

# if you have already merged master into my/branch :
git diff my/branch^...master
```

This will show you the diff between "the merge base between `my/branch` and `master`", and `master`.
This is the diff that `git` views as : the changes that were committed to `master` and not to `my/branch` yet.